# How to store multiple key value pairs in Java Map as "put()" overwrites the previous data

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, hashmap

I want to create a HashMap to store data to firestore database. I want store the name and a boolean value based on the pressed button. But the **"put()"** in hashmap **replaces** the previous values, i.e the name and the boolean value. And i get only the last value in the database.

Here is the use of put to store data in the Map.

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.present:
            attendance.put(name, true);
            nextCard();
            break;

        case R.id.absent:
            attendance.put(name, false);
            nextCard();
            break;
    }
}
```

And the firestore store method..

```
public void storeAttendance(String batch) {
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    db.collection(batch+"sheet").document(date)
            .set(attendance)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w("TAG", "Error writing document", e);
                }
            });
}
```

I want the values for all the students attendance in the database but i get only the single value for the last student.

[The Database structure i get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Ixg.png)

Comment: If your attendance map only has one element after issuing multiple puts then you may be using the same key each time.  Is `name` getting updated before invocation of onClick(..)?

Comment: I see the document in the screenshot with a single name. Can you indicate what you want to achieve? A simple schema would be enough. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212351/does-put-overwrite-existing-values#answer-7212364)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using some sort of Collection?

Process could be like this:

Maintain a List/Set of users/attendance data. 
Each time the present or absent button is pressed, add that users data to the list.

Once the Teacher/Speaker/Event Coordinator is done, they hit the "save attendance" button and at this point you save the List/Set as one object into the HashMap.

Another option is to store each user into the map based on their ID. It all depends on how you plan on using the data.

The map could be id->attendence history, date->list of ids present on the given date, etc. There are many options and it really depends on your use of the data.

If you don't want to overwrite the data in a HashMap, use a different key for the map. If you can't use a different key, then put all the values into a single Collection object and use that collection as your value in the map.

Comment: Yes I am using the HashMap. On every iteration of the loop i want a value to be stored to the collection. After the list is over there is a dialog box. On confirmation it pushes the collection to database. The data is not stored perfectly in the collection. I want to know what is the syntax to store the name and boolean data true or false on every iteration of name..

Comment: try adding this to see if you're overwriting a value in the map: Object o = attendence.put(name, true); if(o != null) *let yourself know you're overwriting by doing something here*

the put method returns the previous value. If it's not null, it's because you just overwrote something

Answer (score 0):

HashMap does not allow duplicate keys; The name variable in your call to .put() needs to be unique for every value you wish to add to the map. Otherwise it will be overwritten.

```
 attendance.put(name, true); //Here the name (key) value needs to be unique for every bool.
```

Comment: As it is in a loop the value of name gets updated in each iteration, hence it is unique in every iteration. But the value of the name in the last iteration is only saved..